# Manage my certificates and provisioning profiles on developer page

Tags: ios

I haven't logged in to my apple developer account for half year. Now, I logged in to https://developer.apple.com/  .

I remember there used to be a link named "**iOS Dev Center**" from where I can manage all my **certificates & provisioning profiles**. But now, I cannot find this link any more. Where can I manage my certificates & provisioning profile now on developer page?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how to use a web site, not about programming

Comment: @matt, I need to manage my certificate to make my iOS project app running on my device. I think they are related. It is part of iOS development to manage certificate etc so that you can run on device instead of simulator. Anyhow, if you want to be that strict, it is fine, but do you happen to know where is the place to manage certificates and provisioning profile on developer page now?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com
2. click Account (Top Right)
3. fill you credentials
4. click 'Certificates, IDs & Profiles'
   [image: my account]

Comment: hmmm.... I don't see 'Certificates, IDs & Profiles', does that mean I don't have any in my account? Strange. Even if so, I don't see any button to allow me to create one either. Are you able to show a screenshot of yours?

Comment: Updated my answer with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

**Provisioning Profiles**

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/

**Certificates**

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/